# Rewriting URL in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite URL using **.htaccess** in **codeigniter** but it's not working. Can you please figure it out. Want to change URL from:

```
www.site.com/mauritius_holiday_rentals/apartment/anyname
```

to

```
www.site.com/mauritius_holiday_rentals/anyname
```

My current .htaccess file contains:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^mauritius_holiday_rentals/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ mauritius_holiday_rentals/apartment/$1 [L,QSA]
```

First four line is for removing index.php from URL which is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If routes file is set to access new url and you want to set redirection for old URLs then Use following code in .htaccess. otherwise let me know in detail what you want to do.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule /mauritius_holiday_rentals/apartment/$1 /mauritius_holiday_rentals/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Routes.php config file code

```
$route['mauritius_holiday_rentals/(:any)']="mauritius_holiday_rentals/apartment/$1";
```

Let me know if any problem.

Comment: Current URL is 
**www.site.com/mauritius_holiday_rentals/apartment/anyname**
But I want to remove "apartment" from URL. The URL I want instead of above URL is: 
**www.site.com/mauritius_holiday_rentals/anyname**

Comment: You can do that in routes.php config file. i have modified my answer for routes config file. let me know if any problem

Comment: I don't want to route. Just want to show different URL but want to run same method.

Comment: route does the same. Please try first.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use codeigniter routing system
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 RewriteEngine On    
 RewriteBase /yourProjectName/    
 RewriteCond $1 !^(images|stylesheets|javascript)    
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /yourProjectName/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Some explanation on how/why this is an answer would prove useful to others.